# Make unique key by combination of 4 fields?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 4 fields (project_id, domain_name, link_log, url) in unique key in my local database for store unique data,

data like -

**project_id**(int)--> 1224; **domain_name** (varchar)--> 'javatpoint.com'; **link_log** (int)--> 0 or 1; **url** (varchar)--> 'http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-tutorial-dependency-injection-by-setter-method'

according to sql the unique show like.. **"1224-javatpoint.com-0-http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-tutorial-dependency-injection-by-setter-method"**

i want same unique key in salesforce.

Comment: so you can easily create unique fields in salesforce. just click a checkbox.

Comment: i want a combination of all 4 field in unique key (project_id-domain_name-link_log-url)
according your comment every field make a unique individually (single filed) ,

Comment: then you can make a formula field but to make it unique you need to handle that in trigger.

Comment: @TusharSharma You definitely do not need trigger. Workflow, Process Builder, etc. are perfectly sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

- create a formula field **A** and use formula **domain__c +"-"+ text(linkLog__c)+"-"+ text(projectid__c )+"-"+ url__c** (**text** use for convert number to text)
- create a workflow (field update) and store data in new filed **B** (Unique Case Insensitive)

Comment: While I wouldn't create the `field A`, the concept is something I'd highly recommend.  You'd want to store the value in a field rather than a formula in a field.  You can then make that field indexable (External ID), unique, and a SOQL query will run a lot better.

Comment: thanks @NickCook for your valuable suggestion ;
i used only workflow (field update) to create unique key .